# Type hint that indicates that class contains method with signature

Tags: python, python-typing

Is it possible to write a type hint which checks if a passed type defines a function with a specific name and signature, if the name of the function and its signature are derived from another argument?

In the following scenario I try to show what I intend to do:
I want to write a type hint for the function `override`, which ideally should generate a warning if `override` is used as an annotation for a function that does not override a corresponding function in the `superclass` (passed explicitly, as argument).

```py
import inspect
from typing import Callable, Protocol

# I would like to type hint the superclass, which should define a function with same signature as `method`
def override(superclass: type):
    def overrider(method: Callable) -> Callable:
        print('checking method ', method)
        if method.__name__ not in vars(superclass) or inspect.signature(method) != inspect.signature(getattr(superclass, method.__name__)):
            raise Exception(f'{method.__name__} does not override a function from {superclass.__name__}')
        return method
    return overrider

class Parent:
    def func(self) -> None:
        print('parent!')


class Child(Parent):
    @override(Parent)
    def func(self) -> None:
        print('child!')


ce = Child()
ce.func()
```

In the code above, I only check at runtime if the `override` is valid, by raising an exception whenever no function in the supposed super class exists with the same signature. Additionally, I would like to receive warnings whenever the child implementation does not match the parent implementation (anymore).

I know that `Protocol` exists for a similar purpose, but I don't think that is applicable in this scenario, because the name of the function (in this case `func`) is supposed to be variable. Otherwise I could define a protocol with a function with the same ParamSpec and return type and utilize matching type hints for the `method` aswell.

As chepner [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75802870/python-type-hint-that-indicates-that-class-contains-method-with-signature#comment133715197_75802870), it might make more sense to pass the function directly to the decorator, because it solves the problem of the variable name of the function. I tried to do that [here](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=f028f92b54e36b53a9bb0b978cae67a5). However, this leads to the necessity to annotate `self` in a `Child` member function as `Parent`, which leads to type hinting problems later on, when attempting to access attributes of the `Child`.

Comment: This might be much simpler if you pass the actual function to override (`Parent.func`) instead of just the type (`Parent`) as the argument to `override`.

Comment: (For example, you can then use a `ParamSpec` to immediately capture and enforce the signature requirement without having to use `inspect` at runtime.)

Comment: (I'm of the opinion that if you can enforce something using static type hints, it's OK to expect the end user to use a static type checker rather than provide a run-time equivalent as well.)

Comment: When I run your gist I get the warning in console "func_fail does not override the function func_fail". (not on the gist website but on my local computer)

Comment: @rassar I think that is the `print` log output that is generated at runtime, when the module the code resides in is imported, and the decorator executed (but ignored by type checkers, i.e., in the IDE).

Comment: I'm trying to understand what the intention of this override decorator is going to be.  If you want to ensure that the signature of a function in a child class matches that of a parent class due to how it will be used in a dependency injection, then Protocols seem to be the way to go, and are the only way you could ensure another user creating a custom class inheriting from Parent also matches the required function signatures anywhere an instance of Parent or its subtypes would be injected.  UNless maybe I'm just completely misunderstanding something here, which is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is interesting - I'm pretty sure that the behaviour you want from your function "`override`" is exactly the purpose of the function...`override`:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.override

```py
from typing import override

class Parent:
    def func(self) -> None:
        print('parent!')


class Child(Parent):
    @override
    def func(self) -> None:
        print('child!')


ce = Child()
ce.func()
```

`override` asserts that the overridden method signature must match that of the parent class. It also ensures the method on the Child class is found on the parent class. Hope this is useful!

Comment: Hey :) in my question I forgot to mention that I cannot use override because I am limited to an older pzlython version, so I had to write a similar functionality myself. But your answer is correct and probably most helpful to other users that encounter this question, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @mutableVoid oh ok no worries, I've actually got some good news for you - most of the newer python typing helpers are available in a library `typing_extensions` for older versions, `override` included - see here: https://typing-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#override