# Hint instance of subtype of type

Tags: python, python-typing

I want to write a type hint that allows a function argument to be an instance of an arbitrary subtype of a previous type (that is derived from a type hint).

I know that `Type[cls]` indicates that we receive a type that derives from `cls`. Is there a way to express that I would like to receive an instance of that type?

```py
from typing import *

CallbackArgs = ParamSpec('CallbackArgs')
CallbackReturn = TypeVar('CallbackReturn')
SuperType = TypeVar('SuperType')

def check(func: Callable[Concatenate[SuperType, CallbackArgs], CallbackReturn]) \
        -> Callable[[Callable[Concatenate[Type[SuperType], CallbackArgs], CallbackReturn]], None]:
    # TODO: in the line above and below this line, I would like to specify, that we accept an instance of an abritrary subtype
    # of SuperType, what I wrote is "I expect an arbitrary subtype of SuperType as first argument"
    def inner(function: Callable[Concatenate[Type[SuperType], CallbackArgs], CallbackReturn]) -> None:
        return None

    return inner


class Parent:
    def func(self, a :int) -> None:
        ...


class Child(Parent):

    @check(Parent.func)
    def func(self, a: int) -> None:
        ...
```

[MyPy playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=1eda15afddf599c9c70b8bf9b095e63f)

My motivation for the question is [Type hint that indicates that class contains method with signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75802870) and [this code sample](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=f028f92b54e36b53a9bb0b978cae67a5) I came up with following the chepner's suggestion in the comments of that question. For now, I replaced `Type[SuperType]` by `Any` in the decorator to supress the warning, but I wonder if there is a more elegant solution, that would also report a warning if I wrongly used `check` for static methds.

Using `SuperType` [results in](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=31ce3922f173f4cd3bdea0a41ce29228):

```
Argument 1 has incompatible type "Callable[[Child, int], None]"; expected "Callable[[Parent, int], None]"  [arg-type]
```

Is it possible to write a type hint that indicates that instances of any type extending Parent are accepted?

Comment: The type for _"an instance of an arbitrary subtype of `SuperType`"_ is... `SuperType`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am not sure if the distinction I made in my question is useful, but I think that your statement above is not correct, because SuperType also allows an instance of SuperType, and in the particular use case above it does not allow instances of the subtype `Child`, because it seems to be incompatible with `Parent` when inside the `Callable` (see second mypy link).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to have to first restate the obvious here:

The type annotation `x: T` expresses that `x` is expected to be of type `T` **or of any subtype of `T`.**

(There is currently no way in Python to express that `x` should be of any subtype of `T`, **except `T` itself**. And it is debateable whether or not that would have any utility.)

The reason your *second* code in the MyPy playground fails is because callable types (*functions* if you will) are **contravariant** in their parameter types (but covariant in their return types). This is explained in detail in [this section of PEP 483](https://peps.python.org/pep-0483/#covariance-and-contravariance) as well as in [this part of the MyPy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#variance-of-generic-types). To paraphrase a bit:

Given `int` is a subtype of `float` and `Manager` is a subtype of `Employee`

> `Callable[[], int]` is a subtype of `Callable[[], float]` 
> `Callable[[], Manager]` is a subtype of `Callable[[], Employee]`

but

> `Callable[[float], None]` is a subtype of `Callable[[int], None]` 
> `Callable[[Employee], None]` is a subtype of `Callable[[Manager], None]`

---

To apply this to your case:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Concatenate, ParamSpec, TypeVar

P = ParamSpec('P')
R = TypeVar('R')
T = TypeVar('T')


def check(
    func: Callable[Concatenate[T, P], R]
) -> Callable[[Callable[Concatenate[T, P], R]], None]:
    def inner(function: Callable[Concatenate[T, P], R]) -> None:
        pass
    return inner


class Parent:
    def func(self, a: int) -> None:
        ...


class Child(Parent):
    @check(Parent.func)  # wrong
    def func(self, a: int) -> None:
        ...
```

By passing `Parent.func` to the `check` function you bind the type variables in it such that `T` is `Parent`, `P` is `int` and `R` is `None`, thus its return type

```py
Callable[[Callable[Concatenate[T, P], R]], None]
```

collapses to

```py
Callable[[Callable[[Parent, int], None]], None]
```

and thus the `inner` function returned by it expects an argument of type `Callable[[Parent, int], None]`.

Using that as a decorator on `Child.func` thus is an error because `Child.func` (being of type `Callable[[Child, int], None]`) is **not a subtype** of `Callable[[Parent, int], None]`.

The *opposite* relationship holds, which you can see, if you do the following instead:

```py
...

class Parent:
    def func(self, a: int) -> None:
        ...


class Child(Parent):
    def func(self, a: int) -> None:
        ...


check(Child.func)(Parent.func)  # passes
```